# Parse XML With PHP Not Working

Tags: php, xml

I have XML:

```
http://localhost:8888/?purp=oclcn&xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <leader>00000cam a2200000 a 4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">33333502</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">951010s1996    vtua     b    001 0 eng  </controlfield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="010">
      <subfield code="a">   95045582 </subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">1858983274</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">9781858983271</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="0" ind2="0" tag="245">
      <subfield code="a">Economic sociology /</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">edited by Richard Swedberg.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="260">
      <subfield code="a">Cheltenham, Glos, UK ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="a">Brookfield, Vt., US :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">E. Elgar Pub. Co.,</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">©1996.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
      <subfield code="a">xv, 574 pages :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">illustrations ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">25 cm.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">The international library of critical writings in sociology ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="v">5</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">An Elgar reference collection</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="500">
      <subfield code="a">A collection of journal articles previously published between 1940-1994.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Aspect sociologique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902116</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902213</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst01123875</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economische sociologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">gtt</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie économique.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">ram</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">ram</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="0" ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Wirtschaftssoziologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">swd</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="4" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="4" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="4" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique - Aspect sociologique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="0" ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Wirtschaftssoziologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(DE-588)4066514-8</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">gnd</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="700">
      <subfield code="a">Swedberg, Richard.</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
```

I wish to retrieve the text in the element that has attribute tag=001. I used the following code:

```
$xml = new DomDocument;
$xmlstring = $_GET['xml'];
$new = $xml->loadXML($xmlstring);
$xpath = new DomXpath($xml);
var_dump($new, $xpath);
$h = $xpath->query('//controlfield[@tag="001"]');
var_dump ($h);
```

The DOMNodeList in `$h` that gets dumped has 0 length. How come? Shouldn't it have one element?

Answer (score 1):

The query string should be in the format `//{root node}/{child node}/..`

Another issue here is that the root node contains the default namespace `xlmns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"`, but `DomXPath::query`only reads the root node without any namespaces.

As such, we've got to register this name space first. The code should look like the following:

```
$xml = new DomDocument;
$xmlstring = $_GET['xml'];
$new = $xml->loadXML($xmlstring);
$xpath = new DomXpath($xml);
$xpath->registerNamespace("ns", "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim");

var_dump($new, $xpath);
$h = $xpath->query('//ns:record/ns:controlfield[@tag="001"]/..');
var_dump ($h);
```

Comment: Thx @Claude. but now we have a new problem. Although one element is dumped, when I use 'foreach ($h as $rowNode) {
    echo $rowNode->nodeValue; // will be 'this item'
}', it doesn't echo out the element value I wish to have.

Comment: Alright. In this case, we can change the query string to be relative (as the previous query string returns _all_ nodes since the root node matches). 

The new query string should be `$h = $xpath->query('./ns:controlfield[@tag="001"]/')`